# What is $\lim_{k \to 0^+} \gamma(k)$ when $\gamma(k)$ is a fraction that contains $O(.)$

Tags: limits

What is $\lim_{k \to 0^+} \gamma(k)$ when

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber % Remove numbering (before each equation)
  \gamma(k) &\sim &  \frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}k +\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}4k^2 + O\left(k^3\right)}{k^{\frac32}-\frac{3}{4} \pi  k^{\frac52}+\frac{3}{32} \pi^2 k^{\frac72} +O\left(k^{\frac92}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I do not know how to deal with $O(.)$ in the fraction. Can I just remove any terms that include $k^n, \quad n\geq 2$ as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber % Remove numbering (before each equation)
  \gamma(k) &\sim &  \frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}k }{k^{\frac32}}?
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Since $\operatorname O_{k \to 0}(k^3) \subseteq \operatorname o_{k \to 0}(k)$ and $\operatorname O_{k \to 0}(k^{9/2}) \subseteq \operatorname o_{k \to 0}(k^{3/2})$, the extra terms do not affect the limit as $k \to 0$ (which blows up).

Comment: @LSpice. What does $\subseteq$ mean in $\operatorname O_{k \to 0}(k^3) \subseteq \operatorname o_{k \to 0}(k)$?

Comment: Big-O and little-o are used as if they stand for individual functions, but they actually stand for collections of functions; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign .  What I [wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979184/what-is-lim-k-to-0-gammak-when-gammak-is-a-fraction-that-contain#comment8210067_3979184) would sometimes more commonly be written as something like "If $f(k) = \operatorname O(k^3)$ as $k \to 0$, then $f(k) = \operatorname o(k)$ as $k \to 0$", or, even more punchily, the asymmetric "$\operatorname O(k^3) = \operatorname o(k)$ as $k \to 0$."

Comment: @LSpice. So It seems the final answer is valid?

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979184/what-is-lim-k-to-0-gammak-when-gammak-is-a-fraction-that-contain#comment8210137_3979184).